# transpose axes on 3 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, transpose

I have a 3 dimensional array of shape (N,4,4) and am struggling in rearranging the axis.

The array looks like

```
A = ([[1.35, 10.30, 2.25, 17.21],
      [1.29, 9.06,  2.21, 15.47],
      [1.37, 9.74,  2.04, 14.44],
      [0,    0,     0,    0]])
```

and I want it to look like

```
A = ([[1.350, 1.290, 1.370, 0],
      [10.30, 9.060, 9.740, 0],
      [2.250, 2.210, 2.040, 0],
      [17.21, 15.47, 14.44, 0]
```

I have been trying [tag:np.swapaxes()] and [tag:np.transpose()] but am struggling and getting confused with multidimensional arrays

Comment: Try A.T or A.transpose().

Comment: You show a 2d array, not 3d, so it's a little hard to tell what you want.  but maybe `np.transpose(arr, (0,2,1))` to keep the N first, and swap the other 2.